# Is creating an index on a column that is already in another multi column index redundant?

Tags: database, indexing

Suppose I have table:

```
FOO
---
A (PK)
B (PK)
```

Where A+B are composite primary keys.

Now let's say I want to use an auto-increment key instead of a composite primary key

```
BAR
---
ID (auto-increment PK)
A
B
```

I'm making this syntax up btw

```
Create Index AB_Index on Column (A,B) UNQIUE
```

If I need fast searches/joins on BAR for A + B, I'm covered by the index.  But what about if I need fast searches/joins for both columns individually?  Would the following be necessary/desirable?  If so, what are the possible ramifications to database size/performance?

```
Create Index A_Index on Column (A)
Create Index B_Index on Column (B)
```

Comment: What type of index is used?

Comment: Since I'm mostly concerned about joins, I suppose non-clustered, but I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: I think the answer depends on what database you're using and what type of index you've created. Not all index types allow efficient lookups when you've created a combined index but some do (and thus, no separate indexes are needed).